# How do I use friendsofcake/crud bulk delete?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, crud

The docs are here: https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions/bulk-delete.html

But what I don't understand is what should my request URL look like in order to hit bulk delete? I assume it is just the usual crud path to the model as a json file using the DELETE method. However this doesn't seem to work.

Presumably that's because I'm mapping it incorrectly to the actions. Here's what I've done as a Controller:

```
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;

class ApiAppController extends Controller
{
    use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

    public $components = [
        'RequestHandler',
        'Crud.Crud' => [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete',
                'Crud.Bulk/Delete'
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                'Crud.Api',
                'Crud.ApiPagination',
                'Crud.ApiQueryLog',
                'Crud.Search'
            ]
        ]
    ]; 
}
```

I also tried the controller like this:

```
use App\Controller\Api\ApiAppController;

/**
 * Devices Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\DevicesTable $Devices
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Device[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class DataController extends ApiAppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->Crud->mapAction('deleteAll', 'Crud.Bulk/Delete');
    }
    public function deleteAll()
    {
        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $results = $connection->execute('TRUNCATE TABLE data');
    }
}
```

With various attempts at the URL like so:

```
DELETE http://my-site:8888/api/data.json
```

```
DELETE http://my-site:8888/api/data/delete.json
```

```
DELETE http://my-site:8888/api/data/delete-all.json
```

```
DELETE http://my-site:8888/api/data/all.json
```

It doesn't seem to even hit the CRUD plugin as I'm getting a CSRF token error. Normal crud routes don't get that CSRF error because they are picked up by the routing:

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
        $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
        $routes->resources('Data');
});
```

The cakephp docs on RESTful routing don't cover how to address bulk actions:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#resource-routes

Answer (score 0):

So there are a number of things I would look at to fix this.

Firstly would be your routing. If you're using `DashedRoute` then the url would be `http://example.com/examples/delete-all.json`. Unless you also pass the `Accept: application/json` header.

You can also set an action as the key in the `actions` config, which can be used to change the action name. [See the documentation](https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#action-configuration).

```php
'actions' => [
    'delete-all' => [
        'className' => 'Crud.Bulk/Delete'
    ]
]
```

As for your CSRF token issue, you will need to unlock the action to be able to use `DELETE` without generating a token.

In your controller
`$this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['deleteAll']);`

Or you'll need to generate a CSRF token and send it with your request. [Read more on CSRF in the book.](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests)